# Howto finish freehand drawing in Openlayers on mouse release

Tags: javascript, draw, openlayers-3

I want to finish drawing when releasing mouse button and not on double click. How can I achieve that?

Right now I use this code to activate freehand drawing on Openlayers [drawing feature](http://openlayers.org/en/v3.11.2/apidoc/ol.interaction.Draw.html) by default:

```
draw = new ol.interaction.Draw({
  source: drawLayerSource,
  type: 'LineString',
  condition: ol.events.condition.singleClick,
  freehandCondition: ol.events.condition.noModifierKeys
});
map.addInteraction(draw);
```

But I don't know how to avoid double click to finish the line string and use mouse release instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**UPDATE** - https://jsfiddle.net/jonataswalker/frwfuzzn/

To enable both freehand and straight lines, I'm calculating the elapsed time between the drawing start and pointerup with this function:

```
var isStraightLine = function(){
  var now = new Date();
  // `start_time` was set at the drawing beginning
  var diff = now - start_time;
  // strip the ms
  diff /= 1000;
  already_checked = true;
  // an average time I found here
  // not sure if this is completely reliable
  return diff < 0.07;
};
```

If I find this is a freehand drawing finish with `draw.finishDrawing()`. Better check the code for the sake of understanding.

---

I could but only if you stay with `freehandCondition` default condition - [`ol.events.condition.shiftKeyOnly`](http://openlayers.org/en/v3.11.0/apidoc/ol.events.condition.html#.shiftKeyOnly).

Listen to `pointerup` on `ol.Map` and if you are drawing, finish with [`ol.interaction.Draw#finishDrawing`](http://openlayers.org/en/v3.11.0/apidoc/ol.interaction.Draw.html#finishDrawing).

```
var start_drawing = false;
var draw = new ol.interaction.Draw({
  source: vectorSource,
  type: 'LineString',
  condition: ol.events.condition.singleClick
});
map.addInteraction(draw);

draw.on('drawstart', function(evt){
  start_drawing = true;
});
draw.on('drawend', function(evt){
  start_drawing = false;
});
map.on('pointerup', function(evt){
  if(start_drawing) {
    draw.finishDrawing();
  }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jonataswalker/ewv0mo3c/

Comment: Actually it does work also with freehandCondition noModifierKeys, but you have to remove maps dragPan: https://jsfiddle.net/geraldo/tfcy010q/1/

Comment: Now the only improvement would be to make work also straight line drawing. As you can see in the jsfiddle, line gets started when you click but is no finished as drawend is called immediately. The problem is that I can't figure out how to differentiate between mousedown and mouseup on different positions.

Comment: And how straight line will be finished? Standard `dblclick`?

Comment: As you can see in the jsfiddle, `dblclick` doesn't finish it as it first detects `pointerup` and sets `start_drawing` to false.

Comment: ok, I didn't explain myself: I want to maintain the possiblity of drawing straight lines. In your fiddle it starts to draw the line on a single click but deletes it on the second click. I would like to finish it (means show it as drawn) on the second click.

Comment: In updated fiddle you start a straight line and to finish with double click (the standard). That's why I asked you in other comment.

Comment: Thanks for your follow up - but your solution doesn't work for me. Probably it's related to your average time of 0.07 you put into the code.

Using [setActive](http://openlayers.org/en/v3.11.2/apidoc/ol.interaction.Draw.html#setActive) I got a more elegant solution with straight line getting finished on dblclick: https://jsfiddle.net/tfcy010q/2/

Comment: If you found the solution I'm glad to know.

Comment: Thanks again, the solution is in the last fiddle I posted.